# clone a Django model instance object and save it to the another model having same fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
obj = Foo.objects.get(pk=<some_existing_pk>)
obj.pk = None
obj.save()
```

```
class Foo2(Foo):
    pass
```

This method works if we are cloning objects to same model.
What to do if we have another model `Foo2` Which is inherited from `Foo`consisting of same fields of `Foo`
I want to save `obj` to `Foo2`. Is there a shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to hash the result from .get() query.

```
obj = Foo.objects.get(pk=<some_existing_pk>)
data = dict(obj.values()[0])
# pop the pk
data.pop('id')

# pass the dict as **kwargs
Foo2.objects.create(**data).save()
```

Comment: what if Foo Model has a ManyToManyField, will it work?

Comment: i have tested the code with models.ForeignKey() and it works without any change to the data dictionary

Comment: it works for me with ManyToManyField too. Thank you:)

Comment: and also `get()` doesn't have `values()` method, we can use `filter()` instead